# Haanga include template with parameters

Tags: php, html, django, templates, include

In Django you should be able to do something like this:

```
{% include "fragments/threadComment.html" with post.comments as comment only %}
```

But we are using Haanga witch it based on Django and i was told to follow Django documentation when i got some problems with Haanga but i cant get this part to work.

Is this even supported in Haanga?

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Haanga_Compiler_Exception: Haanga_Compiler_Exception: Unexpected T_WITH(with) in /var/www/project/templates//pages/postThread.html:5 in /var/www/project/framework/lib/Haanga/Compiler/Parser.php:155 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/project/framework/lib/Haanga/Compiler/Parser.php(2253): Haanga_Compiler_Parser->Error('Unexpected T_WI...') #1 /var/www/project/framework/lib/Haanga/Compiler/Parser.php(2364): Haanga_Compiler_Parser->yy_syntax_error(36, 'with') #2 /var/www/project/framework/lib/Haanga/Compiler/Tokenizer.php(570): Haanga_Compiler_Parser->doParse(36, 'with') #3 /var/www/project/framework/lib/Haanga/Compiler.php(256): Haanga_Compiler_Tokenizer::init('{% extends "bas...', Object(Haanga_Compiler_Runtime), '/var/www/projec...') #4 /var/www/project/framework/lib/Haanga/Compiler.php(356): Haanga_Compiler->compile('{% extends "bas...', '/var/www/projec...', '/var/www/projec...') #5 /var/www/project/framework/lib/Haanga.php(378): Haanga_Compiler->compile_file('/var/www/projec...', false, Array) #6 /var/www in /var/www/project/framework/lib/Haanga/Compiler.php on line 399

Answer (score 0):

I never used Haanga but in Django, the syntax for passing variables to included templates is `with varname=value`, not `with value as varname`

So try:

```
{% include "fragments/threadComment.html" with comment=post.comments only %}
```

Comment: Tried that did not work, i believe the error occurs at "with" that also raise the question if it even is supported.